# New Relic License Key Validation

Tags: javascript, newrelic

I need to implement a function to check if a provided **New Relic** *license key* is valid (as in existing or active) in a JavaScript application.

I looked at the documentation but could not find an API endpoint to check this.

EDIT: To be clear, we will not have API keys available to hit an API endpoint for example and read the http status from the JSON response - while that would be a solution, we will only have the license key available for this validity check.

Answer (score 1):

Just call any of their endpoints, if your api key is wrong it will respond with an error message saying that. Doing it this way all their endpoints are a license key checker.

You will get a json response something like.

```
{"error":{"title":"No API key specified"}}
```

Comment: I apologize and will edit the question to be clearer, but we do not and will not collect API keys, only the license key is provided and is all we could use to establish that the key is indeed valid

Comment: Have you looked into the query keys section of [nerdGraph](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/nerdgraph/examples/use-nerdgraph-manage-license-keys-user-keys) that might have something usefull for you.

Comment: I have but unfortunately all queries will require the account ID, which we also do not collect

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you can do to validate the license key except to check that it's a 40 character hexadecimal string. The Ruby agent uses that approach:

```
# A license key is an arbitrary 40 character string,
# usually looks something like a SHA1 hash
def correct_license_length
  key = Agent.config[:license_key]
  
  if key.length == 40
    true
  else
    ::NewRelic::Agent.logger.error("Invalid license key: #{key}")
    false
  end
end
```

[agent.rb:443-454](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-ruby-agent/blob/cab35887936b52d6706d2cef085feefd9a23c461/lib/new_relic/agent/agent.rb#L443-L454)

The agent isn't checking for non-hex characters but you could use this regex to do that if you think it's necessary: `/^[0-9A-F]+$/`.

I imagine most of the time the key is invalid it will be caused by an incomplete paste job (too few characters or none) or some random characters getting appended (typo). In both cases this should cover you pretty well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @thejonanshow.

We already have an implemented check like these on the front-end. However, we have found it to not be sufficient. 

After discussing with folks from `New Relic` we established that such check is not currently possible

Comment: Without being able to identify yourself to the API with an API key you're correct, there's no publicly available endpoint to check if a license key is valid. It would allow a bad actor to brute force search for valid license keys and overwhelm any accounts they find with junk data.

Comment: That is a good point and a valid reason to not provide this kind of validation check through an API check. I had not thought of that.